# Help solving an Integral : $\int_0^{\infty} [t*m^{at} e^{-t\times m^t}]\ \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration

I'm writing my "own thoughts" about escaping local minimas using levy noisem, and I got an Integral that I'm not able to solve, or go any forward, the integral is formulated as follow:

$$\int_0^{\infty} [ t\times m^{at} e^{-t\times m^t}] \ dt$$

Where * is just multiplication, $0<m<1$ , $a$ is just a constant

I tried looking at laplace integral approximation but didn't worked , since $t*m^t$ has a maximum not a minimum , I used this book:
"F. W. J. Olver. Asymptotics and special functions"
and:
"Butler, Ronald W (2007). Saddlepoint approximations and applications. "

I wasn't able to solve it using integration by parts also.

Any idea someone?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @albert1905 welcome to Math stack exchange. If you want you can learn how to use Latex here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: Thanks! won't happen next time